# How to put the contents of a .txt file in a Text field

Tags: python, textbox, tkinter

I am trying to make a very basic note pad program. My only problem though is trying to open a `.txt` file and putting its contents into the main Text field. But I keep getting errors.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.Create_Widgets()

    def Create_Widgets(self):
        self.SButton = Button(self,width=35)
        self.SButton["text"]="Save"
        self.SButton["command"]=self.Save
        self.SButton.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.OButton = Button(self,width=35)
        self.OButton["text"]="Open"
        self.OButton["command"]=self.Open
        self.OButton.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.Cont = Text(self,width=60,height=40)
        self.Cont.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2)

    def Save(self):
        Content=self.Cont.get(1.0,END)
        File = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
        File.write(Content)
        File.close()

    def Open(self):
        Content=self.Cont.get(0.0,END)
        File1 = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
        File2 = open(File1,"r")
        print(File2.read())

root=Tk()
root.title="Basic Notepad"


app=Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `But I keep getting errors` Please edit the exact error message you get into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Tkinter.Text.insert`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.insert-method) to insert the file's text into the textbox:

```
def Open(self):
    File1 = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    File2 = open(File1, "r")

    #######################################
    self.Cont.insert("1.0", File2.read())
    #######################################

    File2.close()  # Make sure you close the file when done
```

The `"1.0"` tells Python where to begin inserting the text.

Comment: Thanks I figured out that ["text"]="Example" would not work after a while but thanks a lot now it can  open text files